# React dnd && FullCalendar

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, react-dnd

Is there a way to take event FROM FullCaledar and put it onto another element like trashbin?
Can I do it with useDrop? What should I use in accept?

I found this example, but I don't have enough experience to change it into React+hooks.

I have a Calendar and a thashbit. I need to move events to it to remove them

```
const Schedule = () => {
 const [, dropTarget] = 
  useDrop({
     accept: "???",
     drop(???){
     dispatch({type: "REMOVE_EVENT", payload: id})
    }
 })
return(
       <DndProvider backend={Backend}>
               <FunkFullCalendar
                        today={() => {
                            let startDate = moment().tz(timeZone, true).startOf('week');
                            let endDate = moment().tz(timeZone, true).endOf('week');
                            changeInterval(startDate.toISOString(), endDate.toISOString());
                        }}
                        timeGridWeek={() => {
                            setView('timeGridWeek');
                        }}
                        allDaySlot={false}
                        defaultView='timeGridWeek'
                        view={view}
                        events={sessions}
                        eventDragStart={handleDragStart}
                        eventDragStop={handleDragEnd}
                        dateClick={(evt) => {
                            let correctedDate = moment(evt.date).utc().tz(timeZone, true);
                            createSession(correctedDate);
                        }}
                        drop={(evt) => {
                            let correctedDate = moment(evt.date).utc().tz(timeZone, true);
                            createSession(correctedDate, evt.draggedEl.dataset.actorid);
                        }}
                        eventClick={(evt) => {
                            openSession(evt.event.id);
                        }}
                        eventChange={(evt) => {
                            let correctedStart = moment(evt.event.start).utc().tz(timeZone, true);
                            let correctedEnd = moment(evt.event.end).utc().tz(timeZone, true);
                            changeSessionTime(evt.event.id, correctedStart, correctedEnd);
                        }}
                        startDate={startDate}
                        endDate={endDate}
                                            />
               <BinSection ref={dropTarget}/>
         </DndProvider>
    )
}
```

I searched a lot, but haven't found the solution